# iOS UIDatepicker accessibility with overridden minute interval

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uidatepicker

I am using a UIDatePicker with a "time" mode and setting minuteinterval property to 30. I do see the time picker displaying time options in increments of 30 so that part works. The issue is accessibility where when i focus on the minutes section it keeps saying (00 minutes, picker item, adjustable, 35 out of 60). My problem is with the 35 out of 60. Shouldn't it read 1 out of 2 Since there are only two options (0 and 30)?

[Screenshot of voiceover focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s571.jpg)

Here is the code I use to setup the datepicker

```swift
datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 200)

// Set some of UIDatePicker properties
datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: I'd guess that in that picker spans 30 hours so there are at 60 total options, alternating between 00 and 30. So your selection is on the 35th option out of 60 total.

Comment: but with the picker you can select hours, I'd like hours to go from 0-12, and minutes to just have two options 0 and 30 @ckundo do you know how to do that?